# What is the Python code related to collection actions for blender 2.8?

Tags: python, scripting, collections

2.8 is new and I can't find how to:

- Create a new collection.
- Add selected object to collection "name here" .
- Add selected object to collection created in the same code.

Could someone show me how?

i found this and this in the API

https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.Collection.html
https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.BlendDataCollections.html

Comment: Who down voted this? This question is awesome. Get out of here, haters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here an example i made, it will place the active object to a new collection. 
it's a really simple example i hope it can help the beginner (like me) out there.

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object
obj_old_coll = obj.users_collection #list of all collection the obj is in

new_coll = bpy.data.collections.new(name="COLLECTION TEST") #create new coll in data
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(new_coll) #add new coll to the scene
new_coll.objects.link(obj) #link obj to scene

for ob in obj_old_coll: #unlink from all  precedent obj collections
    ob.objects.unlink(obj)
```

here another examples:

```
import bpy

A = bpy.context.object
A_old_coll = A.users_collection #list of all collection the obj is in

terrain_coll_name = "Scatter: ["+A.name+"]"+" Terrain"
if terrain_coll_name not in bpy.data.collections: #if this collection name is not in all collection already:
    terrain_coll = bpy.data.collections.new(name=terrain_coll_name) #create new coll in data
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(terrain_coll) #add new coll to the scene
else:
    terrain_coll = bpy.data.collections[terrain_coll_name] #else let re use the already existing one

terrain_coll.objects.link(A) #link obj to terrain coll

for ob in A_old_coll: #unlink from all  precedent obj collections
    ob.objects.unlink(A)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this question (and related links) useful, so thought I would respond here even though the original query is now quite old.

I found the code you have adapted quite hard to follow. Mainly because of my lack of Python experience but partly because of the additional checks (number of selected objects > 0 and create new collection if one doesn't already exist).

This version is less sophisticated, but is perhaps easier to follow and it resolves the [2] related error.

```
import bpy

#create list of collection names
CollList = ['Structure', 'Architecture', 'Biscuits']

#Find length of collection list (could just use '3' in this case, but I prefer to have a general case)
CollLen = len(CollList)

#create collections from the list
for x in range(0,CollLen):
    y = bpy.data.collections.new(CollList[x])
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(y)

#create list of all selected mesh objects
ListObjects = [ x for x in bpy.context.selected_objects if x.type == 'MESH' ]

#run through list and move objects
for z in ListObjects:
    bpy.data.collections[NewCollectionName].objects.link(z)
```